# Implicit or different way I could use to convert from radians to degrees mode?

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator, degrees, radians

I understand the title may be vague, but bear with me on the details:

I have a calculator application I am making using Tkinter. And what I want to do is allow a functionality that allows the user to switch modes from Radians to Degrees. These are what the buttons look like:

```
btn_Deg = tk.Button(bottom_frame, padx=16, pady=1, bd=4, fg='white',bg = 
'#666666', font=('arial', 18), width=2, height=2,text="Deg",relief='flat', 
command=lambda: convert_deg()).grid(row=1, column=0) #TODO

btn_Rad = tk.Button(bottom_frame, padx=16, pady=1, bd=4, fg='white',bg = 
'#666666', font=('arial', 18), width=2,height=2,text="Rad",relief='flat', 
command=lambda: convert_rad()).grid(row=1,column=1) #TODO

btn_Grad = tk.Button(bottom_frame, padx=16, pady=1, bd=4, fg='white',bg = 
'#666666', font=('arial', 18), width=2, height=2,text="Grad",relief='flat', 
command=lambda:convert_grad()).grid(row=1, column=2) #TODO
```

I want to add this functionality because the trigonometric functions always return radians, and I want a way to do this without using degrees(x):

```
sin(x) # returns result in radians!
cos(x) # radians
tan(x) # radians as well
degrees(sin(x)) # will return result in degrees
# great, but is there a way where we can do this:
sin(x) 
# and return the result in degrees instead of radians?
# I need it this way otherwise when I am on "Degree" mode, the entry bar in 
# my calculator would look like this:
degrees(sin(x))
```

I'm sure you are wondering why wont you just use the conversion method built into the math module. And the reason for this is; if I wanted to default every sin, cos and tan related function to degrees, then my application would look something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw7z7.jpg

This is clearly a problem. If a user wanted to convert to degrees they would not want this degrees(sin(x)) text in the entry to pop up EVERY time they were to make a normal calculation while in the degrees mode. That is not how a real calculator works.

And the reason it looks like this, would be because the entry bar is all a string, and all of the text is using eval to evaluate that string. And if I try to use the conversion degrees(x), then IT would just show up on my entry bar, as you saw in my image above.

sum_up = str(eval(self.expression)) # where self.expression is whatever expression is inside the entry bar!
So that is why, I want to know if there is a particular way to somehow default a result as degrees without having to necisarily do this:

```
degrees(sin(x))
```

I would like the conversion to somehow be implicit, if this is possible. And it is because we are switching modes on a calculator, the degrees conversion faactor must be implicit.

I would appreciate if anybody has any suggestions, methods or ways I can approach this problem of conversions.

Comment: If you're looking for the user to input degrees rather than radians to sin/cos/tan, shouldn't the functions be: `sin(radians(x))` rather than `degrees(sin(x))`? The return of sin/cos/tan isn't in degrees or radians, the input is.

Comment: Is that how it works?

Either way, Id need to switch modes on my calculator and cant have sin(radians(x)) show up because that is a bit awkward to the user.

Comment: Can you set a global flag and write your own sin function that checks that?

Comment: I actually had a bit of trouble reassigning a function like that. Would it go like this in my class?




    def sin(x):
        sin(x) = sin(x) * conversion_constant